# Can't find R.java in Android Studio 3.6(newest release)

Tags: android-studio-3.6

When I use Android Studio 3.5, I've known where R.java is.

But in Android Studio 3.6, the newest version, the location of R.java is changed.

Where is it? Thanks.

Comment: What you want to do with **R.java**?

Answer (score 2):

The change is in android gradle plugin 3.6, from the official android site:

> Additionally, Android Gradle plugin has made significant performance
>   improvement for annotation processing/KAPT for large projects. This is
>   caused by AGP now generating R class bytecode directly, instead of
>   .java files.

[android studio 3.6](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/02/android-studio-36.html)